# React Tree view with check box option

Tags: reactjs

How to create treeview with `checkbox` option in `react js`. `checkbox` should be place in right side of the tree.

Below is the `json` sample to create a treeiew:

```
var json = [
      { 
        "text": "Parent 1",
        "nodes": [
         { 
            "text": "Child 1",
            "nodes": [
              { 
                "text": "Grandchild 1"
              },
              {
                "text": "Grandchild 2"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
           "text": "Child 2"
          } 
        ]
      },
      {
       "text": "Parent 2"
      },
      {
       "text": "Parent 3"
      },
      {
       "text": "Parent 4"
      },
      {
        "text": "Parent 5"
      }
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this recursive function to achieve this:

```
_createList(item, margin){
      return item.map((el,i)=>{
          return <div key={i} style={{marginLeft: margin}}>
                   {el.text}
                   <input type='checkbox'/>
                   {el.nodes && el.nodes.length ? this._createList(el.nodes, 10) : null}
                 </div>
      })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div >
            {this._createList(json, 0)}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Check the working `fiddle`: https://jsfiddle.net/mayankshukla5031/rm49r11a/

```js
var json = [
      { 
        "text": "Parent 1",
        "nodes": [
         { 
            "text": "Child 1",
            "nodes": [
              { 
                "text": "Grandchild 1",
                 "nodes": [
                     {
                        'text': 'G GrandChild1.1',
                        'nodes': [
                           {
                              'text': 'G G GrandChild1.1.1'
                           }
                        ]
                     },
                     {
                       text: 'G GrandChild1.2'
                     }
                 ]
              },
              {
                "text": "Grandchild 2"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
           "text": "Child 2"
          } 
        ]
      },
      {
       "text": "Parent 2"
      },
      {
       "text": "Parent 3"
      },
      {
       "text": "Parent 4"
      },
      {
        "text": "Parent 5"
      }
    ];
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
    };
  }
  
  _createList(item, margin){
      return item.map((el,i)=>{
          return <div key={i} style={{marginLeft: margin}}>
                   {el.text}
                   <input defaultChecked type='checkbox'/>
                   {el.nodes && el.nodes.length ? this._createList(el.nodes, 10) : null}
                 </div>
      })
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div >
         {this._createList(json, 0)}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="container" ></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response Mayank. How to add expand and collapse icon in tree view left side. Onclick on parent icon i have to expand the treeview.

Comment: Yes its working fine mayank. How to add expand and collapse icon in tree view left side. Onclick on parent icon i have to expand the treeview. and i am using checked : true in json, but in UI default check option its not working

Comment: can you please share the sample code or fiddle link(expand and clopse icon with tree view ), that is my basic requirement

Comment: check the updated fiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/efb1prf2/, i think this is what you want in expand/collapse :) now your problem is solved completely :)

Answer (score 0):

I know that it was a long time ago, but I was looking for this option also and not find it, so I created one myself.

This solution could help someone in the future.

Here is my working demo: [MUI TreeView react](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-euclid-ywcjxt?file=/src/App.js)
I'm using MUI library.