# React Tree View with custom components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, view, tree

guys! Could you please help me? I'm trying to make a tree view with custom components (link in the bottom). Each element also contains a checkbox. I tried with some React tree-view components, but its stylization isn't sufficient for my view. Any advices? Thank you in advance :)
[React Tree View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNxDa.png)

Comment: Welcome! please provide your code so someone can help you further

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make this with your component. Only you use a object and to do recursive function. exemple in [React Tree view with check box option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42360275/react-tree-view-with-check-box-option)

Answer (score 0):

Try out [react-hierarchy-chart](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hierarchy-chart) npm package.
It will allow to add any custom html in nodes.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32584786)